What is the Fourier-series expansion of the following signal?
The signal is $$x_5(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}Λ(t-n)\ u(t-n)$$
wherer $Λ$ is the triangular wave and $u$ is the unit step function.
The author computes the following solution:

I cannot figure out the second term: The Fourier series expansion is given by $x(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x_n e^{jnω_0t}$. Plugging in $x_{5,n}$ I get:
$$
x_5(t)=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(-\frac{j}{2\pi n}\bigg) e^{j2\pi nt}
$$
Moreover after applying Euler's formula I get:
$$
x_5(t)=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\frac{-j \cos2\pi nt +\sin2\pi nt}
{2\pi n}
$$
I cannot simplify it any more.

You missed the terms from $n=-\infty$ to $n= -1$ in your penultimate equation.

Thank you. This gives the correct answer.
